# Kendo dropdownlist value is not passing

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have added a kendo dropdown list in grid while add and edit grid rows. It was working fine but when I set a default value in the dropdown while adding a new row and try saving, it's not passing the selected value. If I change the dropdown selection manually, it works.

```
var ddr = e.container.find('[name="MPD_ALLOW_REF_ID"]').data("kendoDropDownList");
ddr.dataSource.read();
ddr.value(_latest_Allow_id);
```

This is how I set value in new grid row dropdown list. I just want to get the value of selected item.

Answer (score 0):

As your question does not contain a minimum reproducible example I can only give you a best guess answer. To make it work, it looks like you'll need to manually trigger the change event. So after setting the default value, do something like:

```
ddr.trigger('change');
```